# Significance test for comparing two mean Euclidean distances?

Tags: statistical-significance, distance, euclidean

First time poster here, so please let me know if more details are needed! In short, I'm analyzing a dataset that has scores from 98 siblings from 64 families. So some families contributed only one sibling to the dataset, whereas other families contributed more than one. I'm asking the question: are total scores on one variable (we'll call this "RiskScore") significantly more similar within families compared to in the dataset overall?

To try to answer this question, I calculated the mean Euclidean distance in "RiskScore" between sibs in the same families versus any two sibs in the dataset. To calculate the average Euclidean distance within families, I calculated the mean Euclidean distance in "Risk Scores" for each family with multiple siblings, and then averaged these scores. This resulted in an estimate of 1.21 as the mean Euclidean distance in "RiskScores" within families. I then calculated the grand mean Euclidean distance in "RiskScores" between any two sibs in the dataset, which yielded a score of 1.08.

I'd now like to report on whether the difference between these two mean distances (1.21 vs. 1.08) is significant, but am a little lost on how to do this. A paired t-test seems wrong, but conceptually I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what would be more appropriate. Many thanks for any tips!

Comment: I wonder whether the intraclass correlation would help here. We have a tag for it [tag:intraclass-correlation].

Comment: @mdewey - Oh wow, yes, this is exactly what I need! Thank you so much for your response!